# Regarding Dynamic List to DataTable and Use of TypeDescriptor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reflection, datatable, casting

I know that this question has been asked here before and a number of solutions were also suggested, however, after going through a lot of posts and trying many many suggested solutions, I was able to get the desired result using the simple code given below in `**Style 3**` while others failed. I wanted to ask why `Style 2` failed and how `Style 3` worked. I was under the impression that `System.Component.TypeDescriptor` is what we are supposed to use to get property names from Dynamic objects. Any information that would help me to understand will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
public void EmailExcel([FromBody] MvJson json)
    {
        var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json.Json);
        dynamic dyn = dict["gridData"];
        dynamic off = dict["OfficeIdList"];
        List<dynamic> responseList = new List<dynamic>(dyn);
        List<dynamic> officeIdList = new List<dynamic>(off);
        if (officeIdList != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in officeIdList)
        {
        var gridData = responseList.FindAll(x => x.OfficeId == item.OfficeId);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = ToDataTable(gridData);  <<<<---ISSUE
        ds.Tables.Add(dt);
        var fd = ConvertToExcelByte(ds);    
    }

**<<<<< STYLE 1 >>>>>>**
        public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);
            <<<<<ISSUE>>>>>
            PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                var values = new object[Props.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
                {

                    values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return dataTable;
        }

**<<<<< STYLE 2 >>>>>>**
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            {
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            }
            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                {
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                }

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return table;
        }

**<<<<< STYLE  >>>>>>**   **WORKED**
        public DataTable ToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataTable = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (typeof(DataTable)));
            return dataTable;
        }
```

Comment: could you share the specific error/exception you got by running the other methods? or make it more specific about how it's failed? I've tried a simple test against the second method with a simple type `T` and it works without any exception, check it out here https://dotnetfiddle.net/pYxRzr

Comment: @KingKing in Style2  "PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T))" does not return the "Key" properties of objects in the list but rather returns "Capacity","Count" attributes. I am trying to put the datatable in an Excel, the second method does not throw any exceptions but creates an excel file with columns as"Capacity","Count" which are not the "Keys" in my List of object

Comment: you should share the type `T` you have. As you can see for a simple type of T (as in my demo above), the `DataTable` is built correctly. When you said it has `Capacity` & `Count`, looks like your `T` is a collection type? Looks like it means each such collection (corresponding to one row) is a collection of cells (used to populate the row) and can be accessed via some indexer or something like that. That does not make much sense to me. As I understand the type T should expose properties whose name match `column name` and values match `cell values`